# MapBox SDK for iOS fire tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl manually

Tags: mapbox

I was wondering if there is a possibility to fire the tapOnCalloutAccessoryControl method for a marker in code? For instance, I have list of all the markers, and when a user clicks a marker in the list, I zoom to that location, but I would love to get the callout to popup. Is this possible? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the callout to pop is different from the accessory control. The latter is the (typically chevron-image) control *in* the callout once it is popped up, the "go to more detail" button, basically.

To get a callout to popup, check out `-[RMMapView selectAnnotation:]` and friends.